# Unable to install the VSTS Agent Azure VM extension

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, build-agent

I am unable to install the VSTS Agent Azure VM extension on an Azure VM. I tried both the Install extension blade in the Azure portal and the Powershell option. When I try from the portal it just gets stuck at transitioning. If I run the Powershell script it gets stuck trying to connect to server.

I was able to install it on another server without any issues. The 2 servers are part of a web farm so they are exact images.

I am following the steps detailed at this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=vsts .

I am trying to deploy from VSTS to an Azure VM.

This is the screen when I try to run the powershell script.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the way Run the installation script on the target servers (shows in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=vsts#run-the-installation-script-on-the-target-servers) also fail  to deploy the deployment group to your Azure VM? And can you share related screen shots for the error you meet?

Comment: There is no error. It just shows "connecting to server" or similar and stays there. I can only try the script again in the next change window as its a production server. If I try to install from the Azure portal extensions blade it doesnt complete either. No error just the status shows "transitioning".

Comment: Can you show the screen shot when running the copied script on your VM by PowerShell (note: the PowerShell should be run as administrator)?

Comment: I've added a screen shot. Last time I ran it it went one step further and tried to connect to the server. This time it got stuck here itself.

Comment: The script downloads the VSTS Agent and then configure it automatically. What's the result if you do it manually?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT the screen shot is from when I run it manually. It just stays on that screen.

Comment: @Bipindas I mean download the VSTS agent and extract it manually. And then run config command to config it manually.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT will this work with deployment groups?

Comment: @Bipindas Yes, it will work.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I've updated the screen shot to the point where it says connecting to server and stays there.

Answer (score 0):

Run the config file directly (from `C:/vstsagent` folder) in cmdline and try again with `dev.azure.com/{organisation name}` url.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Under c:\vstsagent there are 2 folders, A1 and A2. Which config should I run? And what do you mean by try again with dev.azure.com/{organisation name}

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of the vsts agent folder. AFAIK, there shoudn’t be any a1 or a2 folders inside that. Also, can you download and extract the vsts agent file and run the config file manually ( in command prompt as admin). I think someone has already mentioned about it + run in command prompt ( I got the same issue waiting for server when running in power shell)

Comment: A1 and A2 appears be to be duplicated folders when I try to run the extension twice. I cleared them out for a fresh start. When I run config directly it doesn't ask me for the Deployment Group. It only asks for the Agent Pool. It seemed to complete but the server wasn't showing up in the deployment pool.